# Django ListView is not paginating despite paginate_by being set

Tags: django, django-views

Django v3.0

View:

```
class UnreadListView(ListView):
    """
    View to show all unread feed items
    """
    model = FeedItem
    template_name = 'rss/unread_feeds.html'
    paginate_by = 15

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['unread_feeds'] = FeedItem.objects.filter(
            is_archived=False).order_by('-published')
        return context
```

When I print if paginated in template it comes back as true. I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are using the `unread_feeds` variable in your template. This queryset will not be paginated because in your query you are not doing any kind of pagination. Django's `ListView` applies pagination to the queryset that is stored into the `context` dictionary under the key `object_list`.

If you want that queryset (the one that Django's `ListView` buidls for you) to be named `unread_feeds` in your template then set the `context_object_name` attribute of your view to that value, i.e. `context_object_name = 'unread_feeds'`.

If additionally you want to perform custom filtering over that queryset you should override the `get_queryset()` method of your view.

If you also want to order the results then you can set the `ordering` attribute of your view.

Comment: That fixed it. Can you let me know how you figured out about it only working on object_list? According to the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/pagination/), they state "This limits the number of objects per page and adds a paginator and page_obj to the **context**" and I thought I did that via '**context**['unread_feeds'] ='.

Comment: Well, I've been using django for a long time, I know a thing or two of how it works. On the other side it was impossible for django tu atomagically paginate the queryset in your `unread_feeds` var because it does not know anything about it. All these frameworks work by. Probably if you read the docs again you will understand that that statement refers to the queryset that the CBV generates. CBV are great because you save a lot of code, but you need to invest some time learning how they work in order the make the most out of them.